# Python error: int object has no attribute to append?

Tags: python

I can't figure out why my code isn't working, very frustrating. I constantly get the error: int object has no attribute to append (for average.append(i, average//250)). But I can't figure out what exactly is wrong here. Is it not possible to import other definition in append functions?
I hope somebody can help me out! 
Any help with my code in general is appreciated :)

```
def main():
    average = []
    y_values = []
    for x in range(0, 2501, 500):
        for i in range(250):
            average.append(calculate(x))
        average = sum(average)
        print("{} euro, {} worpen".format(i, average//250))
        y_values.append(average//250)

    x_values = [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500]
    y_values = []
    plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
    plt.xlabel("Startgeld")
    plt.ylabel("Aantal worpen")
    plt.title("Monopoly")
    plt.show()

def calculate(game_money):
    piece = monopoly.Piece()
    board = monopoly.Board()
    owns = possession(board)
    dice = throw()
    throw_count = 0
    number = 0
    total_throw = 0

    while not all(owns.values()):
        number == throw()
        piece.move(number)
        total_throw = total_throw + number
        throw_count += 1

        if total_throw > 40:
            game_money += 200

        elif board.values[piece.location] > 0:
            if game_money > board.values[piece.location]:
                if owns[board.names[piece.location]] == False:
                    owns[board.names[piece.location]] = True
                    game_money = game_money - board.values[piece.location]
        return total_throw

def throw():
    dice = randint(1,6) + randint(1,6)
    return dice

def possession(board):
    owns = {}
    for i in range(40):
        if board.values[i] > 0:
            owns[board.names[i]] = False
    return owns

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you share the complete output?

Comment: You're reassigning: `average = sum(average)`.

Comment: You initially have `average` as a list.  Then you sum all of its elements and assign the result to `average`, which is now a number.  At that point, you obviously can no longer append to it.  E.g. suppose it contains [1, 2, 3].  Then the sum is the number 6.  You can't append to the number 6, nor can you "sum" the number 6.

Comment: Note that the error message was very clear about this:  It told you that you can't append to an int, which tells you that `average` was no longer a list, but had been changed to an int.

Comment: @AndrewLi answered on your question
Also looks like you have an error in method calculate `return total_throw` in while body not in function body

Comment: @TomKarzes thank you so much!

Comment: @KirillErmolov so my while function is not correct there... I can't see the mistake :(

Comment: @BoBabo
Your loop will always stop after first loop iteration (because `return` instruction in `while` loop body). I think it is not expected behavior.
 Just remove 4 spaces before `return total_throw` and `return` instruction will work after loop.

Answer (score 0):

You done a small mistake in your code. See my comment below and correct your code accordingly. Good Luck :-)

```
y_values = []
average = []
for x in range(0, 2501, 500):
    for i in range(250):
        average.append(calculate(x))
    #average = sum(average) #This is your mistake. Now onward average will be considered as int object make it like below
    average1 = sum(average)
    print("{} euro, {} worpen".format(i, average1//250))
    y_values.append(average1//250)
```